# Why does throttle set timeout, context and args to null?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So I'm just trying to understand the code for throttle in underscore.js.

```
_.throttle = function(func, wait, options) {
    var context, args, result;
    var timeout = null;
    var previous = 0;
    options || (options = {});
    var later = function() {
        previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : _.now();
        timeout = null;
        result = func.apply(context, args);
        context = args = null;
    };
    return function() {
        var now = _.now();
        if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
        var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
        context = this;
        args = arguments;
        if (remaining <= 0) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = null;
            previous = now;
            result = func.apply(context, args);
            context = args = null;
        } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
            timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
        }
        return result;
    };
};
```

I was wondering why context, args and timeout are set to null. I originally thought that they were being set in order to aid garbage collection. To test that I created a large string, passed it into a function and throttled that function. I took two snapshots using Chrome Dev Tools - the first with the lines that set the three variables to null commented out and one with the lines not commented out.

```
var dummyFunc1 = function(testStr) {
  console.log("HELLO");
};

var dummyFunc2 = function(testStr) {
  console.log("BOOM");
}

var dummyFunc3 = function(testStr) {
  console.log("STOOP");
}

var testStr = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
  testStr += i;
}

var largeThrottled1 = _.throttle(dummyFunc1, 1000);
var largeThrottled2 = _.throttle(dummyFunc2, 1000);
var largeThrottled3 = _.throttle(dummyFunc3,1000);

largeThrottled1(testStr);
largeThrottled1(testStr);
```

However, it doesn't seem like there is much difference.

[image]

So why are those lines there?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that it has to do with preventing memory leaks, as you already figured.
Let's assume you create a very large amount of throttled functions, call them with a lot of data and then never call them again. Then the function created by `_.throttle` would still keep references to that data around in the closure scope. They are still reachable in theory by the function returned, so the GC would not be able to clean up that data as long as you don't also dispose of the throttled functions. So setting those variables to null makes sure that there are no references kept around that are no longer in use, preventing memory leaks.

Comment: They're not reachable after the function created by `_.throttle`'s scope is GC'd, though that may never happen if that scope or its inner scopes contain an `eval` call and will never happen if its scope is the global scope.

Comment: But the function created by `_.throttle` may never be GC'd because they are being kept around. Maybe you have thousands of objects that know how to update themselves, with the update function being throttled. Just because you have those things lying around, does not mean that you want to keep the context, args etc from the last call around.